# Extended Events Under Management Folder Not available

Tags: sql-server, ssms

in SSMS, I see that we have a folder called Management and I am expecting Management events to appear like below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FglfY.png)

But My SSMS looks empty like this.
What can i do make Management Events appear under Management Folder.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48Hb8.png)

Comment: It seems you are using the old, unsupported SQL Server 2008 version.

Answer (score 0):

You should check your SQL server version. The extended event was introduced for the first time in 2008.

To check the version you can execute this:

```
Select @@Version
```

Also check the version SSMS and check if its compatible with the SQL Server version.
SSMS version is available under this menu:

```
SSMS > Help > About
```